# How to control 12v water pump by arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno

I have arduino uno and I've bought [12 Volt/350 GPH Seaflo Electric Bilge Pump](https://www.amazon.co.uk/12-Volt-350-GPH-Seaflo-Electric-Bilge/dp/B00OCHCRBC), how to control it directly from arduino?

Comment: Google for MOSFET and you should find the start of a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to control it directly. You need relay module (better one is with opto coupler).

Or you can use some N-Mosfet like IRF540 with antiparallel fast diode to supress induced high voltage from coil. However arduino output might be weak for fast charge/discharge mosfets gate and it gets hot.